# Why does the navigation only work correctly when the backing bean is session-scoped?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, glassfish-3

Consider the following page (header and stuff omitted for brevity):

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText 
            id="theInput"
            value="#{theBean.text}">
            <f:ajax render="theButton" />
        </h:inputText>
        <h:commandButton 
            id="theButton" 
            value="Result" 
            disabled="#{theBean.disabled}"
            action="result" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

`TheBean` looks like this:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class TheBean {
    String text;

    public TheBean() {
        this.text = "test";
    }

    public String getText() {
        return this.text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public boolean isDisabled() {
        return this.text.equals("test");
    }
}
```

`result.xhtml` is a placeholder that displays some static text.

The idea is to enable the button only if the entered text is valid (in this case different from the default). It works, and the button is correctly enabled if I enter something other than `test`, but when I click on the button, it does not navigate to `result`. However, it works if I do one of the following:

1. I make the button always enabled. This baffles me, because in the example above the button is correctly enabled, it only does not navigate to the next page. Why would that change if I leave it enabled all the time?
2. I change the scope of `TheBean` to `@SessionScoped`. I do not understand this either. How can the scope of the backing bean influence the page-navigation? Everything else in the example seems to work just the same with `@RequestScoped`.

I would really like to keep `TheBean` request-scoped. Is there any way to make it the navigation work without making it session-scoped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bean is request scoped which means that every single HTTP request (also ajax requests!) creates a brand new bean. When you change the input, then the ajax request creates a new bean and sets the value. When you press the button, then the normal request creates a new bean (thus the value set by ajax is lost!) and determines if the button is eligible to be invoked -which is not- and thus won't invoke the action.

The view scope is designed to overcome exactly this kind of problems. Put the bean in the view scope.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TheBean {
```

This way the bean will live as long as you're interacting with the same view by either normal or ajax requests.

Sorry, I don't know how from top of head what the proper CDI declaration is. It's at least called "conversation scope".

Comment: Thanks. It seems that `@ConversationScoped` is intended for this, but it requires the use of long-running conversations, and I cannot get that to work. I will return to this issue later. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, is there any particular reason to prefer CDI annotations over JSF annotations? I'm always curious as to why people prefer that. As far I've never seen a real advantage.

Comment: It is really only because I want to use dependency-injection. I don't really have a reason for that, as I am only learning all these technologies. DI seems to be the ideal tool for decoupling front- and back-end. If you tell me that there is a simpler way, I am still very impressionable.